# How to find how many numbers and letters are on a string

Tags: c#, string, letters-and-numbers

I'm validating passwords. I need to check how many letters and numbers there are in a password. If there were less than 2 numbers or less than 2 letters, the user should be warned about an invalid password.

Comment: What language or other tools are available?

Comment: sorry I completely forgot, I'm coding on C# using visual studio 2013 as programming environment.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Regex, especially if your password requirements are rigid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each character in the password, check against the ASCII table and count letters and numbers appearances:

[image]

Consider adding special characters to the validation.